# Can sharding solution be done after DB is already populated an runnning

Tags: mysql, database, scalability, sharding

I wanted to know if there are sharding solutions for MySQL that can be applied on large databases that are already running in the cloud. For example, I have a 500GB database on Amazon RDS, but now I want to use a sharding solution (you will tell me which one i hope) that can scale my database using sharding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot directly divide it into shards. Because sharding requires data to be physically separated. You will have to plan a downtime after testing a solution which works for you best.

I recommend scalebase. Refer http://www.scalebase.com/tag/mysql-sharding/

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work at [Clustrix](http://www.clustrix.com/)

ClustrixDB was designed exactly for the use case you describe -- scale your database, live, as it grows. ClustrixDB was built from the ground up to scale (it is not a MySQL bolt-on solution) and is MySQL compatible and available on AWS. As your data set ClustrixDB automatically distributes data in the background and distributes queries across multiple servers, all the while providing a simple SQL interface.